# Node js application crashing at more than 1000 requests

Tags: node.js, load

I have written REST API using node js. On this I was trying to do a load test using artilery.io but when there are 200 concurrent users with 10 requests per second the app crashes i.e. this doesn't process any requests after this. I know I can scale this using clusters but for now is there a way to restart the sever so we can use the application after a load crash?

UPDATE:
Hi i tried  using pm2 but when i do a load test the server doesn't get restarted I checked in Logs the server is never stopped it just hangs.

I tried pm2 start and when running load test i was looking at pm2 monit CPU usage never hit more than 70%.

Thanks

Comment: Do you use any process manager for Node.JS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not know if it will help you or not but If you need to restart the process for memory issue you can use this type of config for PM2.

```
 {
   "name"   : "max_mem",
    "script" : "big-array.js",
   "max_memory_restart" : "20M"
 }
```

If the process hits 20MB RAM pm2 will restart the process.

Answer (score 0):

You can auto restart the server by using the service called pm2. For more details go through http://pm2.keymetrics.io/

Comment: forever (https://github.com/foreverjs/forever) and supervisord (https://github.com/Supervisor/supervisor) also have similar features

Comment: Agree. pm2 turns out better for many people. I'm just putting other options for sake for completeness.